# Python imports packages not present in environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, python-packaging, miniconda

After having uninstalled and removed tensorflow, the package is no longer present in the current environment's conda/pip package list.  Neither are there any associated files present in the current directory.  How then, is it possible to import the tensorflow package without a **ModuleNotFoundError** ? Strangely, the module can be imported but it is not possible to print its version.  What is the explanation for this in python?

Package not found:

```
(base) $ which python
/Users/foobar/miniforge3/bin/python
(base) $ pip show tensorflow
WARNING: Package(s) not found: tensorflow
(base) $ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/foobar/miniforge3

(base) $ conda list tensorflow --full-name
# packages in environment at /Users/foobar/miniforge3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```

Package not in module list:

```
(base) $ python3  
    Python 3.9.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Feb  1 2022, 21:27:43) 
    [Clang 11.1.0 ] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> help("modules")
```

Package is able to be imported even though it is not in module list:

```
    >>> import tensorflow as tf
    >>> tf.__version__
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: `python3 -m pip show tensorflow`

Comment: You probably have more than one Python environment. This is much easier to do without realizing it than you might imagine. You've probably uninstalled `tensorflow` from one environment but it is still present in the other.

Comment: `python3 -m pip show tensorflow` returns not found

Comment: @BoarGules is there a command to list all possible environments that a python session might search in?

Comment: Do you maybe have a file called `tensorflow.py`? That would explain not having an expected attribute like `__version__`.